# Having trouble initializing array values with push in JavaScript for Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Here is my spreadsheet for testing purposes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m8_ck9hvxIXohMjGBTX17uvOui0P4KjsTwF8M72MSFg/edit?usp=sharing

What I am trying to do is find all values > 15 in a 2D range in the spreadsheet tab "InvoiceBackup", then list their order numbers and prices on a separate tab. I used Logger.log() to log every possible step where things were going wrong, and found a few, notably the line when I logged the value of mainArray and it looked like the last three rows were null after it should have 5 rows with values in them. Anyway if you take a look at the sheet you can see there are lots of problems with mainArray, and I have no idea how to solve them, I'm really new to JavaScript. The script works fine when each order# has only one box with > 15 pints, but if a single order has multiple it gets all messed up.

The 2 named ranges are 1) Columns ABC of InvoiceBackup, and 2) columns P to AE of InvoiceBackup
My entire code is below:

```
function MoreThanFifteenPints () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var OrderWarehouseTable = ss.getRangeByName('OrderToWarehouse').getValues();
  var PintsInBoxesTable = ss.getRangeByName('PintsInBoxes').getValues();
  var mainArray = []; // the main table that will be returned
  //MTFP == More Than Fifteen Pints
  var IndicesOfMTFP = []; //row index
  var ColumnIndexMTFP = []; // column index of pints in boxes table where value is > 15
  // find the Indices of MTFP
  for (var i = 0; i < PintsInBoxesTable.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < PintsInBoxesTable[i].length; j++) {
      if (PintsInBoxesTable[i][j] > 15) {
        IndicesOfMTFP.push(i);
        ColumnIndexMTFP.push(j);
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log('columns of mtfp: ' + ColumnIndexMTFP);
  Logger.log(' indices of mtfp: ' + IndicesOfMTFP);
  for (var i = 0; i < IndicesOfMTFP.length; i++) { // initialize mainArray DOESN'T SEEM TO WORK CORRECTLY
    //mainArray[i] = new Array(5);
    mainArray.push(OrderWarehouseTable[(IndicesOfMTFP[i])]);
  }
  //  Logger.log('first first mainarray is ' + mainArray + 'mainarray length is ' + mainArray.length);
  /**
  for (var i = 0; i < IndicesOfMTFP.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('indicesofMTFP[i] = ' + IndicesOfMTFP[i]);
    mainArray.push(OrderWarehouseTable[IndicesOfMTFP[i]]);
    Logger.log('FIRST MAIN ARRAY [I] IS EQUAL TO: ' + mainArray[i]);
    Logger.log('main array inside for loop is ' + mainArray);
  } */
  Logger.log(' FIRST MAIN ARRAY IS: ' + mainArray + '<-- mainarray length is ' + mainArray.length);
  //mainArray.
  Logger.log('FIRST MAIN ARRAY [3] IS EQUAL TO: ' + mainArray[3]);
  //return IndicesOfMTFP;
  var PintsNumArray = []; // array of Pint numbers to add to mainArray
  for (var i = 0; i < IndicesOfMTFP.length; i++) {
    PintsNumArray.push(PintsInBoxesTable[IndicesOfMTFP[i]][ColumnIndexMTFP[i]]); //not 100% sure if this is working correctly
      //mainArray[i][3] = PintsInBoxesTable[IndicesOfMTFP[i]][ColumnIndexMTFP[i]];
    //Logger.log('PintsNumArray[i]= ' + PintsNumArray[i]);
  }
  Logger.log('PintsNumArray = ' + PintsNumArray);
  for (var i = 0; i < PintsNumArray.length; i++) {
    //Logger.log('PintsNum [i].length= ' + PintsNumArray[i].length);
    mainArray[i].push(PintsNumArray[i]); //this is not working correctly
    mainArray[i].push(getPrice(PintsNumArray[i]));
    Logger.log('mainarray[i] is: '+ i + ': ' + mainArray[i]);
    Logger.log('main array IN THE FOR LOOP is ' + mainArray);
  }
  Logger.log('mainarray[0]: ' + mainArray[0]);
  Logger.log('mainarray[1]: ' + mainArray[1]);
  Logger.log('mainarray[2]: ' + mainArray[2]);
  Logger.log('mainarray[3]: ' + mainArray[3]);
  var Total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < PintsNumArray.length; i++) {
    Total += mainArray[i][4];
  }
  //return PintsNumArray;
  mainArray.push(['Total',,,,Total]);
  //mainArray[mainArray.lastIndexOf()][0] = 'Total';
  return mainArray;
}

function getPrice(PintQty) {
  var BasePrice = 10.05;
  if (PintQty > 15) {
    PintQty = PintQty - 15;
    PintQty = (PintQty * 2.5) + BasePrice;
    return PintQty;
  } else return 'Enter a Qty greater than 15';
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Your test data consists of orders where the qty is always >15; what do you want to do if there is an order with multiple boxes, and not all of the boxes have >15 points. For example, "14, 15, 16" - only the last box has more than 15; or "20, 12, 12, 30"; the 2nd and 3rd boxes have less than 15.

Comment: This function morethanfifteenpints() is meant to ignore everything less than 16, because everything 15 and less is accounted for in the columns to the right of AE on invoicebackup. In the case of 14, 15, 16, on the same order, only the 16 box would be picked up by this function and added to the list on the tab Morethan15Pints.

Answer (score 0):

You are recording details of orders that contain more than 15+ pint boxes. Your code is working, but you are getting multiple loops values.

One of the challenges with your scenario is that the number of 15+pint boxes varies from order to order; a consequence is that the length of each array representing an order with more than 15+ pint boxes may vary. Therefore, the first process is to loop through all the orders and establish the maximum number of 15+ pint boxes in any single order. This value can be used later to create a consistent length for each order containing 15+ pint boxes.

The following code uses conventional loop code to evaluate each order. Features to note:

- `var plus15output = orderqtyValues[v].filter(function predicate(x) { return x > 15 });`: returning box count greater than 15 pints

  - `if (plus15output.length>maxplus15count){`: tracking the value of number of 15+ pint boxes per order to the maximum for all orders.

---

**Test data**

[image: Test data]

---

**Output data**

[image: Output data]

---

```
function so5924149003() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // define the Invoicebackupsheet  
  var orders = ss.getSheetByName("InvoiceBackup");

  // get last row of data on Invoice Backup (named range distorts actual last row)
  var Avals = orders.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  // known zero-based parameters for Invoice Backup
  var orderqtystart = 16; //zero-based
  var orderqtystop = 31;//zero-based
  var orderqtycols = +orderqtystop-orderqtystart+1

  // get the range for the header
  // get the range for the orders
  var orderheaderValues = orders.getRange(1, 1,Alast, 3).getValues();
  var orderqtyValues = orders.getRange(1, orderqtystart,Alast, orderqtycols).getValues();

  // count the maximum number of boxes per order with more than 15 pints
  // need to know this, so that each row has the same number of values
  var maxplus15count=0;
  for (var v=0;v<orderqtyValues .length;v++){
    var plus15output = orderqtyValues[v].filter(function predicate(x) { return x > 15 });
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: v="+v+",length = "+plus15output.length);
    if (plus15output.length>maxplus15count){
      // update max count
      maxplus15count = plus15output.length;
    }
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the max number of 15+ pint boxes in an single order is "+maxplus15count);

  // great temporary array for the final output
  var temppintdata = []


  // loop through the orders on Invoice Backup
  for (var i=0;i<orderheaderValues.length;i++){

    // create and reset temporary array for each order line
    var temporder=[];

    // establish whether there are any 15+ pint boxes in this order
    var plus15 = orderqtyValues[i].filter(function predicate(x) { return x > 15 });
    var plus15length = plus15.length
    if (plus15length ==0){
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", do nothing");
    }
    else{
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", 15 plus on this row");

      // define the order#, shipping methiod and warehouse, then push those values onto array
      var ordernum = orderheaderValues[i][0];
      var shipmethod = orderheaderValues[i][1];
      var warehouse = orderheaderValues[i][2];
      temporder.push(ordernum);
      temporder.push(shipmethod);
      temporder.push(warehouse);

      // loop through box details
      for (var q = 0; q<plus15length;q++){
        // push 15+pinjt values onto the array
        temporder.push(plus15[q]);        
      } // end of plus15 loop

      // test if the number of 15+ pint boxes for this order is less than the maximum qyty of all orders
      // if yes, then pad out the array so that each line has the same number array length
      if (plus15length<maxplus15count){
        for (var l=0;l<maxplus15count-plus15length;l++){
         temporder.push("");
        } // end for     
      } // end if

      // finished looping through the order
      // now push this order line onto the temporary array
      temppintdata.push(temporder)

    } // else

  } // end for

  // check that there are actually some orders with 15+ boxes
  if (temppintdata.length>0){
    // define the target sheet
    var morethan = ss.getSheetByName("MoreThan15Pints");
    //get the last line containing data
    var mtAvals = morethan.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
    var mtAlast = mtAvals.filter(String).length;
    // update the target sheet with the temporary array.
    morethan.getRange(mtAlast+1,1,temppintdata.length,maxplus15count+3).setValues(temppintdata)
    Logger.log("Completed: updated details of orders with 15+ pint boxes")

  } // end if
  else{
    Logger.log("there were no orders with 15+ pint boxes")
  }
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... Just ended up initializing the values of the array the long way, not sure why this works and my old method doesn't, but oh well

```
  for (var i = 0; i < IndicesOfMTFP.length; i++) {
    mainArray[i] = new Array(5);
    mainArray[i][0] = OrderWarehouseTable[IndicesOfMTFP[i]][0];
    mainArray[i][1] = OrderWarehouseTable[IndicesOfMTFP[i]][1];
    mainArray[i][2] = OrderWarehouseTable[IndicesOfMTFP[i]][2];
  }
```